# Saving a dataframe along with metadata to a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to write my data to text file pandas dataframe with multiple columns, but in file I see 3 column in line with "\" symbol at the end of the line and below this all line I see next columns,which I want in one line with the 1sts columns of dataframe.

For example:

```
 Money Honey Boney   \
1. 34 34 464
2.
.....
Yargen Newrte Ederblade
1. 34 45 545
2
...
```

My steps:

```
1. wedew= open('file.csv','w')
2. wedew.write('\n' + str(df) + '\n')
3. wedew.close()
```

How can I see all column in one line correctly without "\" and using my way (w\o 'to_csv')?

Comment: @fontanych why not just `df.to_csv('filename.csv')` ?

Comment: No,not for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to save the string representation of a dataframe in a file, that's not what it's meant for. Use a method that is actually supposed to be used when saving to a file. Try `to_csv`.

```
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

If you want to save your file as a TSV (with tabs as delimiters), you'd add a `delimiter='\t'` parameter inside the function call.

Comment: It is not what I want,coz I add additional info in file.

Comment: @fontanych Then open the file in append mode and add it. Who's stopping you?

Comment: @fontanych So, did you figure it out?